# Simple Javascript syntax behaving unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, html

It is showing 60 + 5 as 605 instead of 65

```
g = document.getElementById("height1").value * 12;
alert(g);    <---- This is showing 60
h = document.getElementById("height2").value;
alert(h);   <---- This is showing 5
b = g+h;
alert(b);    <---- This is showing 605
```

Any ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javacript is not a strongly typed language. It does it's best to interpret the type of variables and generally, if you try to *add* a string-like variable to an integer-like variable, it will interpret it as string concatenation.

You could force the variables to be interpreted as integers like this:

```
 b = parseInt(g) + parseInt(h);
```

Or, using other *tricks* that will force the variable to become numeric, like this:

```
 b = (g*1) + (h*1);
```

Comment: Make sure to [always include the radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters) when calling `parseInt()`

Answer (score 3):

Use `parseInt()` to convert to integer. `+` in Javascript is both for adding and concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

how about b = (g+h)?

make sure the vars are integers, else convert them to integers

Comment: ok then use b = parseInt(g)+parseInt(h)

Answer (score 0):

If the values of those HTML elements are strings (like in text input boxes?) then what you're doing is concatenating strings, not adding numbers.

You need to 1) be sure the input values are actually numeric, and 2) convert the string to an integer using `parseInt()`.